# ComponentDidUpdate usage and Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a setting screen where I get number of info from user such as age, weight and gender and after this info I am calculating how much water user should drink per day.

I would like to calculate this amount automatically without any need of calculate button.

> Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

My current code to calculate water amount

```
  //function to calculate how much water to drink
  waterCalculator = () => {
    //let weightPound = this.state.weight * 2.2046;
    let weightValue = this.state.weight;
    let ageValue = this.state.age;
    let waterAmount = null;
    if (ageValue < 30) {
      waterAmount = weightValue * 40;
    } else if (ageValue >= 30 || ageValue <= 55) {
      waterAmount = weightValue * 35;
    } else {
      waterAmount = weightValue * 30;
    }
    this.setState({ sliderValue: waterAmount });
  };
```

This how I want to automatically update my water amount

```
  //checking if age and weight and gender states are changed call the function
   componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
     if (
       this.state.age !== prevState.age &&
       this.state.weight !== prevState.weight &&
       this.state.gender !== prevState.gender
     ) {
       this.waterCalculator();
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid componentDidUpdate entirely by doing it when weight, age, or gender changes i.e.

```
onChange = name = e => {
  this.setState({ [name]: e.target.value }, this.calcSliderValue);
}

calcSliderValue = () => {
  if (all_inputs_are_filled) {
    this.setState({ sliderValue: x });
  }
}

<yourGenderInput onChange={this.onChange('gender')} ... />
<yourAgeInput onChange={this.onChange('age')} ... />
```

Comment: But in `componentDidUpdate` there isn't a check against `sliderValue`, so it won't trigger `this.waterCalculator();`. It will not cause infinite loop because of that

Comment: Agreed that your proposed solution works better for his scenario. Upvoted

Comment: I have different functions to update state for each input age, weight and gender etc. To use your solution, I need to create calcSliderValue and call this function on each handler. Right?

Comment: Thanks Isaac, well I'll do the same back at you since you found the technical reason :P @sinan yes in that case you would call it in each function, but be aware if you're checking state values you should call it using the second arg to setState as I have done

Comment: Thanks @Dominic and Isaac for your collaboration and solution offering. Eventually I have removed componentDidUpdate and call my waterCalculator function on each state updator function and used it as a second arg

Answer (score 5):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState) { // <===Error

}
```

The problem is with the first argument in `componentDidUpdate` is `prevProps` not `prevState`

To fix the problem

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  ...
}
```

Simply place `prevState` into second argument